# Changing the application icon on android by code

Tags: android

I have a pratical need that is changing the application icon by code, when i firstly launched the app.
Note:
It is not only changing the shortcut icon but also changing the application icon.
How can i resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Launcher Aliasing](http://derekreynolds.wordpress.com/2012/06/09/how-to-have-multiple-launcher-icons-in-one-android-apk-install-for-different-activities/)You can have predefined app icons
and can have launcher activity aliasing